# How do I break out of an sql query infinite loop

Tags: php, sql

running this outputs every result from 100 to 165 times. Seems like an infinite loop, but i've got no clue how to break out of it or identify the problem. Any help is appreciated.

```
    $sql = "SELECT *
FROM timetable t, class c, room r
WHERE c.id = t.class AND t.week = '".$_GET['week']."' AND t.id = '".$_GET['class']."' 
ORDER BY CASE
          WHEN Day = 'Sunday' THEN 1
          WHEN Day = 'Monday' THEN 2
          WHEN Day = 'Tuesday' THEN 3
          WHEN Day = 'Wednesday' THEN 4
          WHEN Day = 'Thursday' THEN 5
          WHEN Day = 'Friday' THEN 6
          WHEN Day = 'Saturday' THEN 7
      ELSE Day
     END ASC, Hour;
";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "Timetable of the class: ".$_GET['class']."";
    echo "<table>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $dan . "</td><td>". $row["ura"] . "</td><td>". $row["razred"] . "</td><td>" . $ucilnica . "</td><td>" . $row["ucitelj"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: *"Seems like an infinite loop"* - I can't see "how" you're closing/ending that (while) loop and the related `if(...)`.

Comment: Good point -  I didn't think it was relevant as it's written in another language, and i translated this part of the code into English so i could get help - ill close this and open a new question. Thank you! Edit: nevermind, ill just edit the question. Still new to this site.

Comment: It looks like you're missing a "{" right after "while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())". That won't fix your loop, but is a problem. Also print out num_rows and see how many you're really getting.

Comment: You're correct, I forgot to copy it when I was editing my question - apologies! This problem started when I joined 2 tables together - Timetable and class - I can show you how its supposed to look like (only using the Timetable table) http://prntscr.com/kny8sl , and here's how it looks like after joining tables http://prntscr.com/kny971 It doesn't stop there, it repeats every result, multiple times.

Comment: Your not selecting anything in your where clause for the `room` table, so it will select all of them for every combination.

Comment: @NigelRen you should post that as an answer.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you very much! Solved! How do I mark this as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the link to the `room` table, so it is selecting all rooms for each combination.

```
SELECT *
FROM timetable t, class c, room r
WHERE r.? = ?.? AND c.id = t.class AND t.week ...
```

You can also try the new JOIN notation...

```
SELECT *
FROM timetable t
JOIN class c ON c.id = t.class
JOIN room r ON ?
WHERE t.week...
```

I would also suggest looking into prepared statements to protect against SQL injection etc.